# XML Schema XSD TotalDigits vs. MaxInclusive

Tags: xml, xsd

I have run across an XML Schema with the following definition:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ClassRankType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

However, it seems to me that `totalDigits` is redundant.  I am somewhat new to XML Schema, and want to make sure I'm not missing something.

What is the actual behavior of `totalDigits` vs. `maxInclusive`?

Can `totalDigits` always be represented with a combination of `minInclusive` and `MaxInclusive`?

How does `totalDigits` affect negative numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> can totalDigits always be represented with a combination of minInclusive and MaxInclusive?

In this case, yes. As you're dealing with an integer, the value must be a whole number, so you have a finite set of values between `minInclusive` and `maxInclusive`. If you had decimal values, `totalDigits` would tell you how many numbers in total that value could have.

> How does totalDigits affect negative numbers?

It is the total number of digits allowed in the number, and is not affected by decimal points, minus signs, etc. From [auxy.com](http://www.auxy.com/study/xml_notes/04.Adding_XSD_restrictions/):

> The number specified by the value attribute of the `<xsd:totalDigits>` facet will restrict the total number of digits that are allowed in the number, on both sides of the decimal point.

Comment: so u mean i want to use totaldigits then i will have to use MinIncusie and MaxInclusive compulsorily  ??

Comment: No, you don't have to. If you don't want to specify a range, but you just want to make sure people don't go crazy using a million digits or something, you can use totalDigits without minInclusive and maxInclusive.

Comment: so is totaldigits actually conceptually "max total digits" or the exact required number of digits?

The quote "facet will restrict the total number of digits that are allowed in the number" is still ambiguous about it.

I found it it's actually max, not the exact from another source online.

Comment: @ahnbizcad The `<xs:minInclusive value="1"/>` indicates that it (`totalDigits`) is meant as a max value. But I don't really understand why `totalDigits` is required for an `xs:integer` in combination with `min[In/Ex]clusive` and `max[In/Ex]clusive`, since Integer != Float. But since the readability is improved, I have nothing against it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

totalDigits is the total number of digits the number can have, including decimal numbers.  So a totalDigits of 4 would allow 4.345 or 65.43 or 932.1 or a 4 digit whole integer as in the example above.  Same for negative.  Any of those previous examples can all be made negative and still validate as a totalDigits of 4.

max and min inclusive/exclusive limit the range of the numbers.  The maxinclusive might seem be a little redundant in your example, but the mininclusive makes certain the number is greater than 0.

Comment: so u mean i want to use totaldigits then i will have to use MinIncusie and MaxInclusive compulsorily  ??

Comment: You would use each of these for their appropriate number restrictions. They can be used individually or together. 
totalDigits specifies the maximum number of digits allowed for ClassRankType (does not count sign or decimal; counts digits on both sides of decimal).
minInclusive specifies bounds for "ClassRankType": number is greater than or equal to 1, you'd use minExclusive for greater than.
maxInclusive also specifies bounds for "ClassRankType": number is less than or equal to 9999, and just like the "min" you could use maxExclusive for less than.